# RSpec one-liner to test object's attributes

Tags: ruby, rspec

Let's assume following situation

```
class A
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

subject { A.new('John') }
```

then I'd like to have some one-liner like this

```
it { should have(:name) eq('John') }
```

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but the syntax you want to use (using spaces everywhere) has the implicatiion that `have(:name)` and `eq('John')` are all arguments applied to the method `should`. So you would have to predefine those, which cannot be your goal. That said, you can use [rspec custom matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-3/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher) to achieve a similar goal:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :have do |meth, expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.send(meth) == expected
  end
end
```

This gives you the following syntax:

```
it { should have(:name, 'John') }
```

Also, you can use [`its`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/subject/attribute-of-subject)

```
its(:name){ should eq('John') }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I found that using **its** method makes it more natural. Can you add it to your answer?

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev added that too.

Answer (score 14):

Method **its** was removed from RSpec https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509. Instead you should be able to do the one liner this way:

```
it { is_expected.to have_attributes(name: 'John') }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
person = Person.new('Jim', 32)

expect(person).to have_attributes(name: 'Jim', age: 32)
```

reference: [rspec have-attributes-matcher](https://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:have_attributes)